# Sometimes the Accusative case article is skipped while sometimes not. Why?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

I have some sentences which have a simple structure of a Subject, Object and Indirect Object.

```
Ich hole dem Hund das Futter.
Er kauft der Frau die Karte.
```

Here `Futter` and `Karte` are in `accusative` case and we have explicitly used `das` and `die` in front of them.

Then there are two other sentences as follows:

```
Wir geben einem Mann Geld.
Sie kauft unserem Kind Schokolade.
```

Here `Geld` and `Schokolade` are direct objects in the sentence, however we have not used the articles in `accusative` form in front of them.

Is there any hidden rule, when to use `accusative` article explicitly and when not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the absence of the definite article in genitival noun phrases](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37696/on-the-absence-of-the-definite-article-in-genitival-noun-phrases)

Answer (score 3):

I realised it's not a duplicate. *Geld* and *Schokolade* are uncountable objects. The same is true for *salt*, *water* or *anger*.

[Unless you're Homer Simpson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIEWgwRrY9s) you can not have one, two or three money. You just have money or not. German shares this grammar property.

**Uncountable** objects are used **without article**. If you want to be specific you have to introduce another quantifier

> Sie kauft ihm Schokolade
> Sie kauft ihm eine Tafel Schokolade
> Sie kauft ihm zwei Tafeln Schokolade (2 chocolate bars)

You can still use the definite article, if the quantity was referenced before or if you talk about a specific quantity.

> A: Ich habe ihm Geld gegeben
> B: Aber nicht das Geld, was auf der Kommode lag?
>
> Das Geld, was ich zurückbekommen habe, habe ich schon wieder ausgegeben
>
> Ich habe heute Futter im Laden gekauft. Später gebe ich das Futter meinen Tieren.

Comment: Aber wir könnten einem Mann das Geld geben und dem Kind die Schokolade, wenn zuvor von einer konkreten Menge Geld oder einer konkreten Schokolade die Rede gewesen wäre, auf die sich das oder die dann beziehen würde. "Die Schokolade war 3 Monate über das Mindesthaltbarkeitsdatum." "Ich habe ein paar Euros mit Gesang in der Fußgängerzone verdient." "Futter" scheint mir auch uncountable zu sein.

Comment: Even the food is uncountable, why does it get the article then?

Comment: @userunknown fixed it for the specific article. However, Euro is countable by definition.

Comment: @infinitezero: Die zwei Sätze mit MHD und Euro sollen der Kontext sein, der es erlaubt dann im nächsten Satz "die Schokolade", "das Geld" zu sagen, sprich, den bestimmten Artikel zu benutzen, wie bei "das Futter" oder "die Karte". Zählbarkeit ist m.E. die falsche Fährte.

Comment: "Wie wäre ich dann ..."? Verstehe ich nicht.Typo, Flüchtigkeitsfehler?

Comment: Wenn Zählbarkeit die falsche Fährte ist, wie wertest du dann "ich kaufe Schokolade" vs "ich kaufe eine Tafel"?

Answer (score 1):

I think `Geld` and `Schokolade` are used in their general terms here, meaning that they don't refer to a specific countable object of `Geld` or `Schokolade`, and more to the general class of `Geld` or `Schokolade`, so the article is dismissed because you  don't refer to a specific countable object.

Another example would be `Ich mag Schokolade`, which would translate to `I like chocolate`.

But when you refer to a specific type of chocolate, like in `Ich mag die Schokolade von Lindt`, this translates to `I like the Lindt chocolate`, where the article suddenly is present as well. So this rule is present in a very similar form in English as well.

So in conclusion it's not about the accusative object itself but to what you refer with it: a specific countable object or item or a general, uncountable class.

Be aware that when referring to the general class, you need to use the plural. This example may not be the best, because `Geld` and `Schokolade` both don't have a plural form applicable in this case, because both are uncountable objects here. A better example would be `Ich mag Autos`, and when we refer to something specific: `Ich mag dein Auto`

Comment: I can also use a car in a general term i.e. not a BMW or a Mercedes, but I still need to use an article.

Comment: Yes, but with `a car` you don't refer to a specific car. As I said, the rule for english is SIMILAR, but NOT THE SAME as the rule in german

Comment: That is precisely my point. According to your explanation it should be "Ich mag Auto" and "Ich mag den BMW". But the correct version would be "Ich mag ein/das Auto". So your conclusion is wrong.

Comment: As I'm not referring to a specific car, it should be `Ich mag Autos`, because you must use the plural when referring to the general class. I know, I didn't add that to my explanation, because Geld and Schokolade are the Same in singular and plural

Comment: [Duden | Geld](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Geld) either is not used in plural **or** the plural is Gelder. The plural of [Duden | Schokolade](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schokolade) is Schokoladen.

Comment: Yes, but that plural is not applicable here, as I mentioned in my answer edit. At least `Wir geben einem Mann Gelder` sounds pretty strange to me. By the way, do you speak German? (No offense intended)

Comment: I think we mixed countable and uncountable objects here, as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I do speak German. I just tried to improve your answer. :)

Comment: Sometimes you seemed a bit aggressive ;) , also because you corrected all my answers given. I fully understand your points, but the truth lies somewhere in-between and we approached the solution from two opposing sides, I think (as is with most two-answer questions).

Comment: I apologize if it appeared aggressive. In my mind I wrote everything in a neutral tone. Of course, writing lacks facial and vocal expressions, so misunderstandings may happen but rest assured I didn't try to attack you in any way. :)

Comment: So, as a suggestion for the future: Don't be to harsh with newcomers, and please write no own answer if only minor improvements are to be made, as that makes it difficult for newcomers to gain points to get "privileges" such as DMs and such, so we wouldn't have to chat using the. comment section

Comment: What is a DM? To be honest, the way the answer started out I was inclined to give it a downvote because it was wrong and misleading but since he's a new user I tried to work it out in the comments. In my opinion it was more than a minor improvement, that's why I posted an original answer. Otherwise I second your opionion.

Comment: With DM I meant "Direct Message", or however it is called on StackExchange, and I fully agree with you.

Comment: If direct message exist on StackExchange, I've never found the button.